# Change Text "Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemIcon.BOOKMARKS"

Tags: titanium, javascript-framework, appcelerator-mobile

Is there a way to change the title of the tab I have a title of 'Library' set but I still see bookmarks as the title can someone explain why this doesn't work or better yet how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try tab.setTitle('Library');

[demo here](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/tabs.js#L39)